# In comparison with doing

Tags: gerunds

Can I use *in comparison with* and *compared to* with gerunds? I tried to find the answer in WordReference Dictionary, but it only says that they can be used with objects, and nothing about gerunds.

1. Learning languages is far more interesting *in comparison with/compared to* sweeping floors, covered by tonnes of dust.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *form* with *function*. Gerund is the *form* that a verb takes when we wish to use it as a noun. Subjects and objects are *functions* that can be performed by nouns, including gerunds. Your reference doesn't exclude gerunds. It simply does not distinguish gerunds from any other kind of noun.

Comment: Nevertheless, is my example with *in comparison with doing* correct?